# .NET Async Queue Processing with a few extras

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, .net-4.6

I'm currently a bit helpless.
I have read a lot of posts about async threading but no one fit my situation and I don't get it to the complete picture.

I have a DB with a table "jobs" that is continuously growing through a application "Importer".
This table have in this example three columns (Id, customer_id, DateOfEntry).
Testdata:

```
1,A,Date
2,A,Date
3,B,Date
4,C,Date
5,B,Date
...
```

I have second application "JobWorker" that should work on that jobs.
BUT with the following restrictions.

I want to start as many async Actions in application "JobWorker" as there are customers, in this example 3.
It's getting harder.
This async workers should have there own queue which always can just work on one job parallel (synchronous).
1) They have to load the oldest job from the table.
2) Work on it
3) Load the next one from the table

Now the tricky part, in reality there are 100 customers but they send not continuously jobs (But I don't know), but I want to work on 10 jobs maximum parallel, in total. (But don't forget just 1 per customer).

How can I achieve this. I know the puzzle pieces (SemaphoreSlim, ActionBlock) but I don't get it to a finished puzzle ;(

[EDIT]
My current try:

```
public class FakeJob
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    public int Duration { get; set; }
}


public class JobMaster
{
    private IConfigurationRoot _configuration;

    private BufferBlock<ActionBlock<FakeJob>> _mainQueue;

    private Dictionary<string, ActionBlock<FakeJob>> _projectQueues;

    private Dictionary<Guid, CancellationTokenSource> _projectCancellationTokens;


    public JobMaster()
    {
        _mainQueue = new BufferBlock<ActionBlock<FakeJob>>(new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 });
        _projectQueues = new Dictionary<string, ActionBlock<FakeJob>>();
    }


    public async Task WorkOnJobs()
    {
        List<string> projectIds = new List<string>() { "Testkunde 1", "Testkunde 2", "Testkunde 3" };
        List<Task> producerTasks = new List<Task>();
        List<FakeJob> jobs = new List<FakeJob>();


        jobs.Add(new FakeJob { Duration = 10, Id = 1, ProjectName = projectIds[0] });
        jobs.Add(new FakeJob { Duration = 10, Id = 2, ProjectName = projectIds[0] });
        jobs.Add(new FakeJob { Duration = 10, Id = 3, ProjectName = projectIds[0] });
        jobs.Add(new FakeJob { Duration = 4, Id = 4, ProjectName = projectIds[1] });
        jobs.Add(new FakeJob { Duration = 4, Id = 5, ProjectName = projectIds[1] });
        jobs.Add(new FakeJob { Duration = 4, Id = 6, ProjectName = projectIds[1] });
        jobs.Add(new FakeJob { Duration = 2, Id = 7, ProjectName = projectIds[2] });
        jobs.Add(new FakeJob { Duration = 2, Id = 8, ProjectName = projectIds[2] });
        jobs.Add(new FakeJob { Duration = 2, Id = 9, ProjectName = projectIds[2] });


        foreach (var loopProjectId in projectIds)
        {
            producerTasks.Add(WorkOnJobsForForProject(loopProjectId, jobs));
        }


        await Task.WhenAll(producerTasks);
    }


    private async Task WorkOnJobsForForProject(string projectId, List<FakeJob> jobDB)
    {
        var consumerOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 };

        while (true)
        {
            foreach (var loopJob in jobDB.Where(x => x.ProjectName == projectId))
            {
                var consumer = new ActionBlock<FakeJob>(StartJob, consumerOptions);
                _projectQueues[projectId] = consumer;

                await _mainQueue.SendAsync(_projectQueues[projectId]);
                await _projectQueues[projectId].SendAsync(loopJob);
                await Task.WhenAll(_projectQueues[projectId].Completion);
            }

            break;
        }
    }


    private async Task StartJob(FakeJob job)
    {
        Log.Logger.Information("Start job [{A}] for [{B}]", job.Id, job.ProjectName);
        await Task.Delay(job.Duration * 1000);
        _projectQueues[job.ProjectName].Complete();
        Log.Logger.Information("Finished job [{A}]", job.Id);
    }
}
```

[EDIT 2]
My current try works with MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 for _mainQueue.
But not for 2 ;(
If I set it to 2, job 9 is not executed ;(

```
public class FakeJob
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    public int Duration { get; set; }

    public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
}


public class JobMaster_BackUp
{
    private ActionBlock<CustomerQueue> _mainQueue;

    private Dictionary<string, ActionBlock<FakeJob>> _projectQueues;

    public static List<FakeJob> FakeJobDB = new List<FakeJob>();


    public JobMaster_BackUp()
    {
        _mainQueue = new ActionBlock<CustomerQueue>(MainQueueJob, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 });
        _projectQueues = new Dictionary<string, ActionBlock<FakeJob>>();
    }


    public async Task WorkOnJobs()
    {
        List<string> projectIds = new List<string>() { "Testkunde 1", "Testkunde 2", "Testkunde 3" };
        List<Task> producerTasks = new List<Task>();



        FakeJobDB.Add(new FakeJob { Duration = 3, Id = 1, ProjectName = projectIds[0] });
        FakeJobDB.Add(new FakeJob { Duration = 3, Id = 2, ProjectName = projectIds[0] });
        FakeJobDB.Add(new FakeJob { Duration = 3, Id = 3, ProjectName = projectIds[0] });
        FakeJobDB.Add(new FakeJob { Duration = 3, Id = 4, ProjectName = projectIds[1] });
        FakeJobDB.Add(new FakeJob { Duration = 3, Id = 5, ProjectName = projectIds[1] });
        FakeJobDB.Add(new FakeJob { Duration = 3, Id = 6, ProjectName = projectIds[1] });
        FakeJobDB.Add(new FakeJob { Duration = 3, Id = 7, ProjectName = projectIds[2] });
        FakeJobDB.Add(new FakeJob { Duration = 3, Id = 8, ProjectName = projectIds[2] });
        FakeJobDB.Add(new FakeJob { Duration = 3, Id = 9, ProjectName = projectIds[2] });


        foreach (var loopProjectId in projectIds)
        {
            CancellationTokenHandler.ProjectCancellationTokens[loopProjectId] = new CancellationTokenSource();
            producerTasks.Add(WorkOnJobsForForProject(loopProjectId, CancellationTokenHandler.ProjectCancellationTokens[loopProjectId].Token));
        }


        await Task.WhenAll(producerTasks);
    }


    private FakeJob GetNextJob(string projectId)
    {
        FakeJob nextJob = FakeJobDB.Where(x => x.ProjectName == projectId && x.IsComplete == false).OrderBy(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault();

        if (nextJob != null)
        {
            Log.Logger.Information("GetNextJob [" + nextJob.Id + "]");
        }

        return nextJob;
    }


    private async Task WorkOnJobsForForProject(string projectId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            FakeJob loopJob = GetNextJob(projectId);

            if (loopJob != null)
            {
                CustomerQueue customerQueue = new CustomerQueue(loopJob);

                await _mainQueue.SendAsync(customerQueue);

                await customerQueue.WaitForCompletion();
            }
        }
    }





    private async Task MainQueueJob(CustomerQueue consumer)
    {
        consumer.Start();
        await Task.WhenAll(consumer.WaitForCompletion());
    }
}


public class CustomerQueue
{
    private ActionBlock<FakeJob> _queue;

    private FakeJob _job;


    public CustomerQueue(FakeJob job)
    {
        _job = job;

        var consumerOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 };
        _queue = new ActionBlock<FakeJob>(StartJob, consumerOptions);
    }


    public void Start()
    {
        _queue.SendAsync(_job);
    }


    public async Task WaitForCompletion()
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(_queue.Completion);
    }


    private async Task StartJob(FakeJob job)
    {
        //Log.Logger.Information("Start job [{A}] for [{B}]", job.Id, job.ProjectName);
        await Task.Delay(job.Duration * 1000);

        JobMaster_BackUp.FakeJobDB.Single(x => x.Id == job.Id).IsComplete = true;

        _queue.Complete();

        Log.Logger.Information("Finished job [{A}]", job.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might take a look at the `Parallel.ForEach()`.

Comment: You should try _something_. Your "puzzle pieces" imply that you've already decided on some particular part of the .NET API for implementation, as opposed to other mechanisms that could accomplish the same thing. So, let's see it. Provide a good [mcve] that shows how far you've gotten, and explain precisely what _specific_ part of the problem you are currently stuck on.

Comment: The TPL Dataflow API may well serve your needs, but I'm not very familiar with it. So I would probably maintain individual queues for each customer, and then a single queue of those queues. Since you want to run oldest jobs first, the queues can be priority queues (i.e. sorted), so you're always dequeuing the oldest first. Then just don't have more than 10 active dequeued queues running at a time; when you're done processing a job, requeue that customer's queue in the primary queue (again, in job age order) and dequeue the next queue to process.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I add my current code. This does one thing right. It just executes one job per customer in parallel. But the max 2 Jobs in total does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This does one thing right. It just executes one job per customer in parallel. But the max 2 Jobs in total does not work.

I don't have a clear picture of exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but I *think* what you're missing is coordination of the different dataflow blocks.

There are a couple of ways to accomplish this. One is to use `SemaphoreSlim`, as you have already noted. You'd create a single `SemaphoreSlim` with maximum count of 10, pass it into the `CustomerQueue` constructor, and have your `StartJob` do a `await WaitAsync` at the beginning and a `Release` at the end.

The other way is by giving the action blocks a scheduler - specifically, the `Concurrent` half of a `ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair` with the concurrency set to 10. You would pass this into the `ConsumerQueue` constructor and set it on the block options.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY VERY MUCH! That was the idea that I needed, my try was much to complicated! :) Man, that cost me time and nervs :) Thanks again. Kind regards